# Isolated view in geoserver

Tags: google-earth, geoserver, arcgis-server

[image]How to achieve Isometric view for units(polygon styles) in geoserver. How to  achieve best look  WMS layer design using geoserver. I need a 2.5d kind of look for my units layer. Is there any tags to be added in sld file. I need the isometric view as shown picture.which attribute i should apply in my sld

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to use the isometric filter function, see this blog: http://mapping-malaysia.blogspot.it/2010/07/pseudo-3d-buildings-in-geoserver.html